# Down-vote rampages on the Go tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, down-votes, users

Every 2 weeks or so it seems like someone or a group of users go around down-voting answers and questions senselessly on Stack Overflow's [go](/questions/tagged/go). Perfectly fine questions and answers in my opinion.

I've noticed the pattern develop because I too tend to lose a lot of reputation during these rampages. Also, they never leave any comments as to *why* the down-votes.

Can this be investigated/checked?

Comment: You have two downvotes in the past month and a half. The one on June 13th is completely justified as pointed out in the comments (i.e. your answer is plain wrong). Could you add a bit of "evidence" in your post so we can assess how important this is?

Comment: Can you see my deleted answers/questions? I'm pretty sure I deleted at least one during one of these periods. I don't seem to be able to.

Comment: No, only mods can see deleted stuff on your profile. If you deleted it, I assume it either was wrong, or wasn't very good - why would you have deleted it otherwise?

Comment: I deleted it to stop losing rep but this question is not (only) about me - other users have noticed this on IRC as well.

Comment: Without some sort of evidence of a problem, it's a bit hard to believe there is an actual issue here.

Comment: "*I too tend to lose a lot of reputation during these rampages*": being a total busybody, I looked at your reputation page (only the 1st page) and it seems like you lost a total of 4 reputation from June 13 to Aug 3 due to these down-vote rampages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're going to have to give us some answers or questions to go off of (ones that have received downvotes).  From what I see, [only posts that should have been downvoted were downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522677/using-buffer-for-read-and-read-operations-examples-in-go/17524477#17524477), and there's no one particular person downvoting your posts repeatedly (enough to trigger the threshold where I'd see the pattern as a moderator).

If you can point to particular posts that you feel *should not* have been downvoted, I can see if there's anything nefarious going on. As it stands, this is just the normal, "some (people) do not agree with you about your posts".

Comment: Holy cow, I went away for 2 hours and this question got from +1 to -7 votes. I agree that I have little to no evidence to present and my question was if this could be investigated since it is based on a gut-feeling I had. I think you proved me wrong, that's all I wanted to know.

Comment: @Tom Your best bet is to flag posts when you get an unusual number of downvotes for moderator attention so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe there is someone who is an expert on Go that only visits the site every two weeks or so. And when she visits the site, and reads the questions and answers that got posted since her last visit, she notices that they are unclear, not useful, or outright wrong. So she quite appropriately downvotes them.

Would you be happier if she visited the site more often and cast one or two downvotes each day, rather than a larger number of them every couple of weeks? I can't really see what the difference would be.

Remember that users are allowed to downvote contributions for whatever reasons they see fit. And they are not required to leave comments explaining *why* they downvoted. It might be *nice* if people left a comment, but it isn't always convenient and it often leads to headaches and pointless arguments.

If there was real abuse going on (i.e., this person was serially downvoting contributions from a single person, like yourself), [there is an automatic process that would handle it by removing those votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: Why assume the person is a _she_ doing the downvotes? :)

Comment: @bluefeet I think he means s/he.

Comment: @Tom I'm aware, just kidding.

Comment: @Cody Thank you that's a theory.

Comment: @Tom, but in English Language: unknown gender should be treated as 'he'.=D

Comment: @Black Yes, according to the traditional view. But some people have adopted the opposite custom as a minor way of working against [deeply-ingrained sexism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutrality_in_English#Pronouns). It would be nice if English had a gender-neutral singular pronoun like Swedish does, but it does not. [E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun) has been suggested, but hasn't caught on outside of niche academic circles (of which I have also, at various times, been a part).